# GLKTextureLoader with texture not in mainBundle

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I'm making an iPhone application with OpenGL ES 2.0 using the GLKit. I'm using GLKTextureLoader to load textures. When my texture sits inside a mainBundle - **EVERYTHING IS FINE**. I get its name with command `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"brushRose.png" ofType:nil]` and the texture  has a following path:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D79492CB-D03C-464D-B06E-00D0DE4389DF/Texture Test.app/brushRose.png
```

When I try to download an absolutely same texture from Internet and store it inside Application's `Documents` folder. Path is like follow:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CD3FBAAB-B8AE-47F5-9C6E-51C854FC1620/Documents/brushes/ps_roses.png
```

I get a **TERRIBLE END RESULT** which can be observed on the picture below:
 [First row - texture from mainBundle, second row - from Documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrOMv.png)

Any ideas how to fix the second case are welcome.

Test project can be found [here](https://github.com/anatolyw/GLKTextureLoaderTest)

Comment: I tried the repository and neither modes worked. It only drew coloured squares.

Comment: @Rhythmic Fistman: I have re-downloaded & rebuild project from scratch + I have tried it on three different devices. It works like expected. Can you, please, provide more details why you can see just squares? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: heh, I was running the project in the simulator. why doesn't it work there? nobody knows. that is a question for another day.

Comment: yes, somehow GLKit OpenGL code does't work in simulator for me as well. I am developing my project on the devices from the beginning. It would be nice to find a solution also for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build an app containing PNGs, Xcode runs `pngcrush` on them which, among other things, [pre-multiplies the alpha](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format).

The "non main-Bundle" files you are using do not have pre-multiplied alpha. This explains the difference in appearance.

Your options are to run `pngcrush` on your url textures, or stop pngcrush running in your project, or conditionally apply the `GLKTextureLoaderApplyPremultiplication` when you load non-crushed PNGs:

```
NSMutableDictionary *options = [@{ GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft : @NO} mutableCopy];

if ( /** png is uncrushed **/ ) {
    options[GLKTextureLoaderApplyPremultiplication] = @YES;
}

NSError* error;
GLKTextureInfo* texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:brushPath options:options error:&error];
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It has solved my problem. I have spent days while trying to figure it out by myself. I have found one extra link [here](https://imageoptim.com/xcode.html) which describes how the pngcrush can be set in xCode for build-in PNGs.

Comment: project on github was updated. See [here](https://github.com/anatolyw/GLKTextureLoaderTest)